# Woocomerce: Php code displayed on Product detail page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have installed WP 6.4.1, and set up a WooCommerce version 8.2.2

On product detail page I see partial php code. Can someone give me a hint what I am missing here and how to troubleshoot this issue?
Thanks

|[image]

Comment: That means you have an extra `<?php` or `?>` somewhere in your code. Have you made any custom code changes to your theme file? Check any product page templates that you've made changes to. You can also turn on [`WP_DEBUG`](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) to find out if there are any PHP errors and where they're originating from.